# Drop on Dock Icon

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, dock

I was looking through the docs to find how to allow dropping on the dock icon.  From what I've seen, it is recommended that you use LSItemContentTypes, as CFBundleTypeOSTypes is deprecated.  However, I can not get LSItemContentTypes to work, only with CFBundleTypeOSTypes being **** will it accept the drops.

How can I do this in a non-deprecated way?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I used in my app's Info.plist to get it to work:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>SomeName</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>None</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.mp3</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Take a look in the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685) to see what each key does exactly.

**CFBundleTypeName** and **CFBundleTypeRole** are required.

**LSItemContentTypes** is an array of [UTIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html). To get the UTI of a file, just type this in the Terminal:

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentType /path/to/file
```

Don't forget to adjust **CFBundleTypeRole** and **LSHandlerRank** to meet your needs.